# Misunderstanding variadic template functions

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am unsure how to achieve a particular effect from a variadic template function I wrote. Below is the function I wrote.

```
template<typename ... T>
bool multiComparision(const char scope, T ... args) {
    return (scope == (args || ...));
}
```

It was pointed out to me that this actually performs something different to what I wanted despite not creating any bugs in the larger scope of my code.

```
multiComparision('a', '1', '2', '3');

=>
   return ('a' == ('1' || '2' || '3'));
```

I had actually intended the function to return the following

```
multiComparision('a', '1', '2', '3');

=>
   return ('a' == '1' || 'a' == '2' || 'a' == '3');
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: You want `return ((scope == args) || ...));`. *"What have I misunderstood"* I'm not sure how to answer, since you seem to know that `(scope == (args || ...))` expands to `('a' == ('1' || '2' || '3'))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I achieve the desired effect?

Wrap your equality comparison expression in parentheses:

```
template<typename ... T>
bool multiComparision(const char scope, T ... args) {
    return ((scope == args) || ...);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bD3EJP)

---

C++14 solution:

```
template<typename ... T>
constexpr bool multiComparision(const char scope, T ... args) {
    bool result = false;
    (void) std::initializer_list<int>{ 
        ((result = result || (scope == args)), 0)...
    };   
    return result;
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_tHuTV)

Comment: Is this supported in C++14?

Comment: @RSahu I believe it is only since C++17. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: @RSahu: added C++14 solution.

Comment: I marvel at your C++ skill. I'll need some time to grok that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

When using C++11 and C++14, you will need an overload of `multiComparision`.

```
bool multiComparision(const char scope) {
   return false;
}

template <typename ... T>
bool multiComparision(const char scope, char arg1, T... args)  {
   return ( scope == arg1 || multiComparision(scope, args...));
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/Z3fTAI

Comment: *"you will need an overload of `multiComparision`"*, not true, see my edit.